# Оптимизация PHP-кода: экономия на спичках

Tags: php, оптимизация

Даст ли улучшение производительности ручной inline функций и замена include содержимым вызываемого файла?

index.php

```
<?php
function hw() {
    echo 'Hello world!';
}
hw();
include('file.php');
?>
```

file.php

```
<?php
echo 'Something text...';
?>
```

Это можно преобразовать в следующее:

```
<?php
echo 'Hello world!';
echo 'Something text...';
?>
```

Вопросы: будет ли прирост производительности? Существуют ли программы для автоматической оптимизации скриптов таким способом?

Comment: В чем проблема самому проверить, использовав этот код и обернув его в вызов microtime()?

Comment: Разница будет, но незаметная т.к. первый ищет файл с названием file.php

Comment: Не понятно конечно в чем проблема ;)
Функция разумеется выполняется намного быстрее инклуда.
Ибо инклуд загружает другую страницу, выполняет в этом случае 2 файла.
Но в данном случае разницу вы даже не увидите

Comment: Преждевременная оптимизация есть плохо. Разберитесь с логикой сначала, какой код и зачем выполняется в отдельном файле. А так, если говорить про сферического коня в вакууме, то да, избавление от инклудов даст прирост и по времени, и по памяти.

Comment: Спасибо всем за ответы. Вопрос дополняется: знаете ли Вы какие-нибудь программы, позволяющие делать это автоматически?

Comment: Если положить в баночку котлеты и залить все компотом, то место будет занято сильно меньше, чем котлеты и компот в бутылке по отдельности. Другой вопрос - а оно вам надо такой ценой?

Comment: @rjhdby, если есть программы, делающие это автоматически - почему бы и нет.

Comment: @Андрей а ошибки вы потом как искать будете? Собственно одна из основных фишек PHP в том и состоит, что "поправил скрипт - сразу доступно новое поведение", а вы пытаетесь ради экономии десятитысячных долей секунды устроить себе проблемы на пустом месте

Comment: @rjhdby, да, поиск ошибок проблематичен. Но, в конце-концов, оптимизирующая программа может оставить комментарии - из какой функции или файла был взят кусок кода.

Comment: @Андрей принцип Парето говорит нам, что "20 % усилий дают 80 % результата, а остальные 80 % усилий — лишь 20 % результата". Так вот ваша хотелка это 90% усилий тех 80%, которая даст 0.001% результата. Но ваше право конечно...

Comment: @rjhdby, кстати, насчёт принципа Парето. То есть, чтоб получить 100% результата, необходимо приложить 100% усилий?

Comment: @rjhdby там несколько наоборот. 100% усилий дают 100% результата. Т.е. приложив на каком-то этапе определенное количество усилий(100% НА ТЕКУЩИЙ МОМЕНТ) вы получаете 100% результата(НА ТЕКУЩИЙ МОМЕНТ), а вот ретроспективный анализ уже дает те самые 20/80

Answer (score 5):

Проблема в том, что этот синтетический тест ничего нового нам не скажет. Со временем первый вариант с 1 файлом превратится в вермишель из кода, который будет трудно поддерживать, а второй будет более читабельным и ради этого стоит экономить 0.00024676322937011s?

По мне не стоит зацикливаться на времени работы программы настолько, чтоб не использовать фишки языка ради ложного чувства скорости, в программах есть более тонкие места в виде подключения и запросов в БД, неправильное чтение файла или медленный алгоритм.

> Если вам нужно ускорить php код, можно использовать HHVM, транслятор от Faсebook, который транслирует php код в код на С++, Doc: https://docs.hhvm.com/, и src: https://github.com/facebook/hhvm

Первый вариант:

```
$a = microtime(true);

function hw() {
    echo 'Hello world!';
}
hw();
include('file.php');

printf(PHP_EOL."%.16f".PHP_EOL, microtime(true)-$a);
```

Время: 0.00040197372436523

Второй вариант:

```
$a = microtime(true);


echo 'Hello world!';
echo 'Something text...';


printf(PHP_EOL."%.16f".PHP_EOL, microtime(true)-$a);
```

Время: 0.00015521049499512

Comment: @Денис, можно хранить код в 2-х экземплярах - один представляет собой обычный читаемый исходник, другой - ту же программу, но оптимизированную.

Comment: @Андрей это очень сомнительная оптимизация, разнице для пользователя нет, или вы ходите сказать что интернет канал это не тонкое место между сайтом и пользователем?

Comment: @Денис, безусловно, интернет-канал является не менее важной составляющей. Но бывают случаи, когда сервер не слишком уж мощный, а посетителей достаточно.

Comment: @Денис, немного удивился Вашему коду: microtime(true) возвращает float, достаточно ведь написать в начале `$t = microtime(true);` и в конце `echo (microtime(true) - $t),PHP_EOL;`.

Comment: @Андрей  у себя использую php v7 и она немного не так работает как в php v5: http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php

Я бы посоветовал бы использовать [hhvm](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/) он значительно ускорит ваш код

Comment: @Денис, ещё [kPHP](https://habrahabr.ru/company/vkontakte/blog/214877/).

Comment: @Андрей у kPHP куча недостатков, нет поддержки lib, только функциональный код ну и PHP v5 only :(, да и они очень странно вышли в open source, просто выложили свой велосипед и забыли о нем, когда Fasebook активно развивает свой продукт.

Comment: @Андрей какую версию php вы используете? Просто если 5 и ниже есть смыл перейти на v7 которая намного шустрее 5

Comment: @Денис, 7.1. Странно, в справочнике не обнаружил каких-либо изменений для microtime() в PHP 7.

Comment: @Андрей да, вы права, поправил

Answer (score 3):

> Будет ли прирост производительности?

[Да](https://github.com/etki/inline-functions-benchmark), это называется инлайнингом. Вызов любой подпрограммы (на каком бы языке вы не писали) всегда требует накладные расходы - прыжки непосредственно по коду, работу со стэком и прочее. Тем не менее, эти расходы практически не имеют особого значения для PHP, потому что он сам по себе достаточно тяжел и его не имеет смысла использовать там, где критична производительность, большую часть времени PHP, как правило, тратит не на работу прцоессора и работу с памятью, а на I/O. В вашем случае куда больше пользы принесет оптимизация БД и работы с ней.

Непосредственно инлайн файла выглядит куда более интересным, однако кэш операционной системы и opcache все равно прокэшируют его после первой загрузки, поэтому дальше плясать нет смысла.

> Существуют ли программы для автоматической оптимизации скриптов таким способом?

Для PHP - нет, и вряд ли будут из-за их ненужности. По-хорошему заниматься этим все равно должен компилятор, но из-за динамической типизации языка это вряд ли возможно осуществить достаточно эффективно.

Comment: в какой-то мере phar

Comment: @rjhdby я сильно сомневаюсь, что он загружается в память целиком, а в этом случае поиск по phar-файлу не отличается от загрузки других файлов с диска.

Comment: @etki, Вы написали о том, что я хотел прочитать - кэш ОС. Как раз благодаря ему эта операция (include) и выполняется достаточно быстро.

Comment: @etki подозреваю, что всё же целиком, если не гигантских размеров. Его ж еще разархивировать надо перед использованием.

Comment: @rjhdby его можно разахивировать в процессе чтения, как все и делают при хранении данных неизвестного объема. А гигантский - это не очень детерминизируемое определение, потому что на каком-нибудь распберри пи и двадцать мегабайт в память запихивать будет не очень хорошо.